# How to handle webbrowser dialogboxes programatically

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I need to click on "OK" button of the dialog box programatically which appears when I click on a button of a website in webbrowser control of vb.net. But when that box appears everyting is getting out of my control, I can not do anyting.

[image]

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$btnApprove" value="Onayla" onclick="return confirm('Bu kişi sisteme kayıt edilecektir. Devam etmek istiyor musunuz?');" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_btnApprove" style="width:100%;" />
```

Do you have any idea how to click any of these buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem.

i found a tutorial on this very issue, here is the link:

http://stateofidleness.com/2011/08/vbnet-webbrowser-dialog-popup-automatic-handling/

Comment: note that the code in the link i provided is fired from a timer (usually) so i dont know if it is exactly what you are looking for. i was working on a scraper and it would get hung up on some such pages, so i just set it check once every 10 seconds, and it enabled my scraper to continue on without user input.